# How to remove header and footer in pdf

Tags: c#, ironpdf

generate html content to pdf using IronPdf, but in pdf generate 3 pages header content and footer in separate pages , how to display in single page hole content.

```
   var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
            //Renderer.PrintOptions.Header.DrawDividerLine = false;
            //Renderer.PrintOptions.Footer.DrawDividerLine = false;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperSize.A4;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.CssMediaType = PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Screen;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperOrientation.Portrait;
          //  Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginTop = 10;  //millimeters
           // Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginBottom = 10;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.Zoom = 125;
            //Renderer.PrintOptions.FirstPageNumber = 1;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.CreatePdfFormsFromHtml = true;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.FitToPaperWidth = true;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Renderer.PrintOptions.FitToPaperWidth = true;
```

pdf will be generate like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phiie.png)

Comment: Can you share the source HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the header and footer as follows:

```
var PDF = Renderer.RenderHTMLFileAsPdf("HTML Body");
PDF.AddHTMLHeaders(new HtmlHeaderFooter() {
HtmlFragment = "HTMLHeader"
});

PDF.AddHTMLFooters(new HtmlHeaderFooter()
{
Height=20,
HtmlFragment = "HTML Footer"
});
```

https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html?q=AddHTMLHeaders#IronPdf_PdfDocument_AddHTMLHeaders_IronPdf_HtmlHeaderFooter_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_System_Boolean_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__